# Python Pandas: create rank columns, move orginal column max rank

Tags: python, pandas, rank

I need to be able to
1. calculate ranks for each column in all rows,
2. the find the max column label of each row,
3. and then in each row move the max ranked column of the original df.

It is trivial to do when working only with the data in the original df. But if different ranking calls are needed, it seems difficult to accomplish.

Below is my Python Pandas code to accomplish this. But it does not work. It does not seem to interpret my statement, `df1['maxV'] = df1[df1['maxR']]` as I expect. Suggestions to achieve will be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy ass np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3),columns=list('ABC')
rankV = df1.pct_change(3) # calculate ranking values
df1['maxR'] = rankV.idxmax(axis=1) # add max ranked column label of rankv
df1['maxV'] = df1[df1['maxR']] # move max ranked column value to maxV
```

Comment: What is an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the rows and accumulate the values in an array:

```
maxVals = [np.nan]*3

for index, row in df1[pd.notna(df1['maxR'])].iterrows():   
      maxVals.append(df1.loc[index, row['maxR']])

df1['maxV'] = maxVals
```

Alternative: A less intuitive way might be to index `df1` using the index and values, which will return a wider Dataframe(# columns equal to # of rows) which has the maxes on the diagonal:

```
maxVals = [np.nan]*3
newDf = df1.loc[df1['maxR'][3:].index, df1['maxR'][3:].values]
maxVals.extend(np.diag(newDf))
df1['maxV'] = maxVals
```

Comment: Just added an alternative solution, not 100% sure which is more time efficient but the 2nd one is less space efficient for sure.